# Electron, TypeScript, absolute paths and best practices

Tags: typescript, electron, absolute-path

I have an issue that I have been tumbling with for a while and I can't seem to get it just right.

I am building an Electron app and I am using typescript, but I also want it to use absolute paths, which I am prefixing with `@/*`. But when I build my files, the paths are not changed and thus remains as I have written them, eg `@/tools/my-helpful-helper`.

**example**

```js
// This type of import
import helper from '@/tools/my-helpful-helper';

// Gets compiled into
const helper = require('@/tools/my-helpful-helper');
```

I have tried a couple of things to avoid this problem:

1. I started with [`ttypescript`](https://github.com/cevek/ttypescript/tree/master/packages/ttypescript) together with [@zerollup/ts-transform-paths](https://github.com/zerkalica/zerollup/tree/master/packages/ts-transform-paths), which worked but I ran into a problem with my library `vanillajs-helpers` where I import the files from `vanillajs-helpers/ts/*`, but that path also remains unchanged, so I have to look for a way to rewrite that path as well or look for a simpler solution.
2. I, therefore, looked at [`ts-node`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) via `electron -r ts-node/register ./src/main.ts`. But with this I run into the same problem as before. When I start the application I keep getting the error about the `@/...` path could not be found.

**My tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node14/tsconfig.json",
  
  "include": ["src/electron/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/*", "public/*"],

  "ts-node": {
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "register": "tsconfig-paths/register" // <-- I don't think this part here works
  },

  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2020",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "@ui/*": ["src/ui/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

#### The actual question

So I guess my actual question here is what is the best way to make all this work? Should I just use a bundler (webpack, rollup, snowpack, parcel, etc.) and get it over with? Or am I missing something that could make my constellation work with just a TS compiler?

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Currently I ened up doing a bundle build with Rollup. Down the line I would probably want to do a Snowpack build, but I couldn't get it to work properly to begin with.